# How to embed latest video from specific YouTube channel in php

Tags: video, youtube, embed

i want embed latest video from my YouTube channel. I want that if i put a new video in my channel then that video should show on my web page. Please help!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412467/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the id of the latest uploaded video in a youtube channel (your channel in this case):

[How to get the id of the latest uploaded video in a youtube channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617567/how-to-get-the-id-of-the-latest-uploaded-video-in-a-youtube-channel)

Send the id of it to database, update the related table's related row. Then embed it to your website:

[How to embed YouTube videos in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412467/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-php)